# simple routing don't work under debian jessie

Tags: linux, debian, routing, router, vmware-player

I'm trying to set up simple enogh system with 3 virtual debian jessie machines: first connected to second and second connected to third. I want first one to be able ping third one.

To achieve this, I've set up static IP addresses (via /etc/network/interfaces) like this:

```
#FIRST:
eth0 inet static address 172.28.11.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
#SECOND: 
eth0 inet static address 172.28.11.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
eth1 inet static address 172.28.18.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
#THIRD:
eth0 inet static address 172.28.18.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Also I've enabled ipv4_forward option in all these machines:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 # /etc/sysctl.conf, all machines
```

and checked that it works (by invoking cat /proc/...../ip_forward and ensuring there is `1` in output)

First can ping second (checked, works). Second can ping third (checked, works).

Now I'm trying to set up simple routing table: I'm adding this route on first node:

```
route add -net 172.28.18.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0 gw 172.28.11.1
```

After it I can ping 172.28.11.2 (second node in other network mask) but still can't reach 172.28.11.1 (third node).

If I do traceroute I see that there *IS* a `172.28.11.1` hop in route (so it TRIES to connect there) but no luck.

What I've missed?

P.S. My config: windows 10 as host, vmware player as virtualization, debian 8 as all guests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you don't mention you added a route on the third system, I'm guessing the problem is that the third system doesn't know how to route return packets to 172.28.11.0/24. So you need to add a route there.

Note that the `route` command has been deprecated in linux for a very long time now. You should familiarize yourself with the `ip` command, it is very powerful and you can do all sorts of interesting routing tricks with it.

You can add the required route on the third system thusly:

```
ip route add 172.28.11.0/24 via 172.28.18.2
```